# How to shutdown JBOSS from jmx-console

Tags: java, jboss

Is it possible to shutdown JBOSS from jmx-console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend!

Google "jboss jmx shutdown"

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ShutDownJBossWithTheJMXConsole